# How to get "subsoups" and concatenate/join them?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have a HTML document I need to process. I'm using 'beautifoulsoup' for that. Now I would like to retrieve a few "subsoups" from that document and join them into one soup so I can later use it as a parameter for a function that expects a soup object.

If it's not clear, I'll give you an example...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

my_document = """
<html>
<body>

<h1>Some Heading</h1>

<div id="first">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div id="second">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div id="third">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<a href="yet_another_doc.html">A link</a>
</div>

<p id="loner">A paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_document)

# find the needed parts
first = soup.find("div", {"id": "first"})
third = soup.find("div", {"id": "third"})
loner = soup.find("p", {"id": "loner"})
subsoups = [first, third, loner]

# create a new (sub)soup
resulting_soup = do_some_magic(subsoups)

# use it in a function that expects a soup object and calls its methods
function_expecting_a_soup(resulting_soup)
```

The goal is to have an object in `resulting_soup` that is/behaves like a soup with the following content:

```
<div id="first">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
</div>

<div id="third">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<a href="yet_another_doc.html">A link</a>
</div>

<p id="loner">A paragraph.</p>
```

Is there a convenient way to do that? If there is a better way to retrieve the "subsoups" than `find()`, I can use it instead. Thanks.

**Update**

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34530943/4408382) advised by Wondercricket that concatenates strings containing the found tags and parses them again into a new BeautifulSoup Object. While it's a possible way to solve the problem, the re-parsing may take longer than I'd like especially when I want to retrieve the most of them and there are many such documents I need to process. `find()` returns a `bs4.element.Tag`. Isn't there a way how to concatenate several `Tag`s into one soup without converting the `Tag`s to a string and parsing the string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SoupStrainer`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) would do exactly what you are asking about and, as a bonus, you'll get a performance boost since it would parse exactly what you want it to parse - not the complete document tree:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

parse_only = SoupStrainer(id=["first", "third", "loner"])
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_document, "html.parser", parse_only=parse_only)
```

Now, the `soup` object would contain only the desired elements:

```
<div id="first">
 <p>
  A paragraph.
 </p>
 <a href="another_doc.html">
  A link
 </a>
 <p>
  A paragraph.
 </p>
</div>
<div id="third">
 <p>
  A paragraph.
 </p>
 <a href="another_doc.html">
  A link
 </a>
 <a href="yet_another_doc.html">
  A link
 </a>
</div>
<p id="loner">
 A paragraph.
</p>
```

---

> Is it also possible to specify not only ids but also tags? For example if I want to filter all paragraphs with class="someclass but not divs with the same class?

In this case, you can make a [search function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to join multiple criteria for the `SoupStrainer`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer, ResultSet

my_document = """
<html>
<body>

    <h1>Some Heading</h1>

    <div id="first">
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    <a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="second">
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="third">
    <p>A paragraph.</p>
    <a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
    <a href="yet_another_doc.html">A link</a>
    </div>

    <p id="loner">A paragraph.</p>

    <p class="myclass">test</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

def search(tag, attrs):
    if tag == "p" and "myclass" in attrs.get("class", []):
        return tag

    if attrs.get("id") in ["first", "third", "loner"]:
        return tag


parse_only = SoupStrainer(search)

soup = BeautifulSoup(my_document, "html.parser", parse_only=parse_only)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: It sounds great, thanks! Is it also possible to specify not only `id`s but also tags? For example if I want to filter all paragraphs with `class="someclass` but not divs with the same class?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `findAll` with passing in the `ids` of the elements you want to use.

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_document)

#EDIT -> I discovered you do not need regex, you can pass in a list of `ids`
sub = soup.findAll(attrs={'id': ['first', 'third', 'loner']})

#EDIT -> adding `html.parser` will force `BeautifulSoup` to not auto append `html` and `body` tags.
sub = bs4.BeautifulSoup('\n\n'.join(str(s) for s in sub), 'html.parser')

print(sub)

>>> <div id="first">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<p>A paragraph.</p>
</div>
<div id="third">
<p>A paragraph.</p>
<a href="another_doc.html">A link</a>
<a href="yet_another_doc.html">A link</a>
</div>
<p id="loner">A paragraph.</p>
```

Comment: But `sub` is a string object, isn't it? It won't behave like a soup, right?

Comment: I suppose it's not possible to create a soup without the additional `<html><body>(...)</body></html>`, right? Also, the repeated parsing and creating the new soup object takes some time. Wouldn't it be possible to construct such soup from the existing one? I.e. only one parsing?

Comment: @geckon `BeautifulSoup` automatically appends the `html/body` tags, but there is a way around that; I will update my answer.

As far as repeating the parsing, I am not sure if there it a way around that. `findAll` returns a `ResultSet`, which is a subclass of `list`. In order to concatenate the results, you will need to cast the items as a `str`, which looses the `BeautifulSoup` status.

Comment: I think I can live with the "additional" `<html><body>` tags after all. The re-parsing might be a bigger problem for long documents, especially when I want to retrieve the most of them and there are many such documents I need to process. `find()` returns a `bs4.element.Tag`. Isn't there a way how to concatenate several `Tag`s into one soup without converting the `Tag`s to a string and parsing the string?

Comment: @Wondercricket I think it's easier to do with a `SoupStrainer` - posted as an answer. Check it out and let me know what do you think. Thanks.