# Need to concatenate two soup tags into a single message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, using

I need to concatenate two soup tags into one and return the result. Can anyone help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    


soup = BeautifulSoup(sub_resp.content, 'lxml')
status_message = soup.find('span', id='MAINFORM:hdrAction')
response_message = soup.find('textarea', id='MAINFORM:textAction')
message = [status_message, response_message]
```

Comment: What do you mean with a single message? The way you're doing it now is to store the information from `status_message` and `response_message` in a list.

Comment: I need to concatenate both the messages into single and return the message

Comment: post a testable markup fragment and expected result

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530587/how-to-get-subsoups-and-concatenate-join-them) might be what you're looking for.